# How would one punctuate a sentence which began as a question but ended with a statement?

Tags: punctuation

The sentence is "Can I ride with you because the other car is already full"

Comment: I would **not** say that that sentence "ends with a statement": it ends with a **reason** for the request.  The **entire** sentence is the request, so it ends with a question mark.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate a quick response. So, would any punctuation be added such as a comma after the word "you"?

Comment: When you speak the expression, would you pause (very briefly) before the word "because"?  If so, you *could* put a comma there, but it is far from essential.

Comment: It is better grammatically and logically to start with the statement of reason and end with the request : 'Since the other car is already full, may I ride with you ?'

Comment: You asked, would any punctuation be added such as a comma after the word "you"?  Answer: like many commas, it's optional, and you get to decide.  This might help: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/190093/112436

Answer (score 1):

Totally depends on the context. If I were writing it as dialogue, I think this way seems the most natural :

"Can I ride with you? ... Because the other car is already full."

Reasoning: assuming you are asking from a perspective of style, and not strictly one of grammar

Comment: I don't disagree but see no reason for three periods there.

Comment: In your version, Because is unnecessary and, arguably, grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence should end with a question mark.

> Can I ride with you because the other car is already full **?**

The more natural way of forming that sentence:

> Can I ride with you? The other car is already full.

The second sentence would be understood as reason from the context.